# Basename For Dir

Tags: php

```
$f = $_GET['f'];
//f = filename i.e file.mp3
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($f));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($f));
ob_clean();
flush();
```

This code works if i have all the mp3 files stored in the root directory but it doesn't if I store them in a separate folder such as /files

I have tried changing the basename and adding a path to `$f` but no luck

Is there a way i can have this code download the files from a dir instead of root?

Comment: This is not just a security issue, it's an invitation to your server ...

Comment: I don't see you actually outputting the file anywhere...

Comment: I forgot to add readfile() it is in there though

Comment: Error messages? (and I agree with @KingCrunch... add some checks!)

Answer (score 1):

Well that would be because `basename` explicitly strips everything but the file name part of the file path. So `basename("foo/bar/baz.mp3")` yields "baz.mp3".

And as others have already mentioned the way you have coded your PHP script is a major security flaw, because now someone could do something like "www.example.com/index.php?f=index.php" and your script (assuming it is located at www.example.com/index.php) would serve up its own source. With a bit of creativity, any external file your script can have access to may be downloaded in that way. Not good, you really do need to restrict the files to a *whitelist* of allowed paths.

Comment: I have created a folder called files so can i restric to only download from there?

Comment: @BrendanMullan You _must_ validate `$_GET['f']` before you use it. How you do it is up to you.